# read an image from a file into an array

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using The imread() function in pyplot module of matplotlib library is used to read an image from a file into an array.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    image_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
    img_data = BytesIO(image_object['Body'].read())
    img = plt.imread(img_data1, format='jpg')
```

Is there any way to read image data into an array without using any library if used then supported by aws. Because I am using for aws lambda

I want a function that can replace the library's tasks

Comment: Why not use those libraries in lambda? That's how it is usually done.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: `image_object['Body'].read()` will read the data into memory.  What do you want to do with this, and why can't you use Python libraries?